# How to correctly search (Real Estate Transaction Standard aka RETS) server?

Tags: api, rets

I am trying to interact with a RETS (Real Estate Transaction Standard) server to find all listings where `matrix_unique_id` field is greater than or equal to 0.

After logging in, I tried the following URI

> Search.ashx?SearchType=Property&Class=Listing&Limit=1000&Query=(matrix_unique_id=0+)&StandardNames=0

The above call returns

```
<RETS ReplyCode="20201" ReplyText="No Records Found."/>
```

But then I supplied a valid Matrix_Unique_Id value like this

> Search.ashx?SearchType=Property&Class=Listing&Limit=1000&Query=(matrix_unique_id=59075770+)&StandardNames=0

Now that returns something but not what I am expecting. The returned value is as follow

[image]

Here is the documentation for [RETS 1.7.2](https://www.reso.org/specifications/) and [a PDF](https://www.nar.realtor/retsorg.nsf/retsproto1.7d6.pdf)

Additionally, here is an example of how to search RETS server for a different server but both adhere to the same specification.

https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/example-rets-session/

Additionally, I used [RETS Connector](http://www.retsconnector.com/) to query the listing and I am able to download listings with no issues which indicated that my account is working and has permission to search.

**Question:** How can I correctly search up all properties where the field `Matrix_Unique_Id` is 0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting full result try the following logic,

```
(ModificationTimestamp=2000-01-01T00:00:00+)
```

This will return all the listings from the year 2000 onwards. If you need further old, give 1990 or older in the query.

> Note: Your example query (matrix_unique_id=0+) is not working because
>   of its pattern may not be correct, say 8 digit number only will take
>   as input.